# Missing argument for the function

Tags: functions, actions

do you know why i am missing argument 2 for this function?

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'notice_handler', 10, 2);

function notice_handler($error_token, $error_tag) {

    ...
    }
}
```

but when i activate the plugin wp says: `Warning: Missing argument 2 for notice_handler()....`

Answer (score 2):

The action is called without any variables:

```
do_action('admin_notices');
```

So you don’t get `$error_token` and `$error_tag`.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually trying to look for the number of variables which it can have. So can I ask if i can replace that action with another? Basically I'm trying to make a plugin which handles the errors of some of my custom plugins.

Comment: Why can't you just invoke those variables *inside* your callback?

Comment: No, because the others plugins when find an error set an option with option_update. Now in the function hooked by <CODE>do_action('admin_notices');</CODE> in another plugin i would like to be able to retrieve the name of the option and so pass it to get_option($var). Is that possible....i may be wrong on this.